# Long-distance Uber/Lyft ride around Christmas

Tags: usa, air-travel, airports, uber

I am flying into Atlanta in the afternoon the day before Christmas. My final destination is a 2-hour ride from Atlanta, in an area that is not connected to Atlanta through public transport or regular shuttle services (specifically, around Clemson). Unfortunately no-one can pick me up at the airport.

The cheapest and most comfortable option I have found so far would be to call an Uber/Lyft once I am out of the terminal.

(I will be tired from the flight and I would rather not drive. Besides, with the Christmas week-end, I would have to book a car for 4 full days, which, together with the drop-off being different from where I am getting the car, makes it more expensive than a 2-hour Uber/Lyft ride. I am also reluctant to book a Uber/Lyft "planned trip" in advance as my flight could be delayed.)

**My question is:**

- How likely am I to find a Uber/Lyft driver willing to take me on such a 2-hour drive around that time?
- Does anyone have experience with such long-distance Uber/Lyft drives, especially around Atlanta?
- Is finding a driver for such long-distance trips a no-brainer or a gamble?

Comment: FYI Uber's "planned trip" feature merely sends an order for a cab at the specified time, it doesn't guarantee that a car would be available.

Comment: This may be tough: Christmas Eve and going to another state; South Carolina might be outside the service/coverage area.

Comment: Finding such a driver in such circumstances is a huge gamble.  I'd resign myself to renting a car, if you can't get a ride.

Comment: Greyhound goes to Anderson starting from Atlanta at 430 pm, otherwise, leaving at 910 am on Saturday. 3 hr 10 min journey, $38 on Friday, $36 on Saturday.

Comment: Clemson University lists a few shuttle services which appear to serve ATL: http://www.clemson.edu/visit/transportation.html .

Comment: Amtrak has daily trains from Atlanta to Clemson, leaving around 8 PM daily and arriving around 10:15 PM.

Comment: Greyhound’s price will change dramatically if purchased less than four days prior.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a guarantee.  You could look on taskrabbit or something and see if there's someone who could take you, but otherwise you may have to risk it with uber.

Saying that, it's certainly possible. Spoke with an uber driver yesterday - they don't get told where the passenger is going until they're in the car, and he liked the surprise of it.

However, a few months ago a passenger got in at the airport and it was a 3.5 hour drive! He double checked that was where she wanted to go, then took her all the way. Got a great hourly rate out of that one, and managed to pick up another person half way back.

The risk you have at busy times is of course surge pricing - it could throw your estimate of the price well out of reach....

You could also load up the uber map at the time you plan on landing the next few days, just to get an idea of how many ubers are around (I did this when wondering about a 4am pickup).